# How can I change the color an individual node in a grid of Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

How can I change the color to a node or edge that already exists on a layout (without deleting/adding it)?

I've got a layout of nodes with preselected positions which I want to change the color (nodes and also edges), but not of every node (or edge). I already tried

```
cy.style('background-color', 'color');
```

, that allows to change the color but it changes the color of every node.

I only want to change the style of one node.

Thanks a lot

Robert

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question. Please provide a [mcve] which shows your problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### **Explanation:**

Hi Robert, you are right, that `cy.style()` changes the style of the whole graph. What you probably didn't notice is, that you can specify really specifically, which element you want to execute this funtion on.

> ### About cytoscape selectors:
>
> If you want to select every element of a specific type, you can call this:
>
> ```
> cy.elements(); // this returns all edges and nodes
> cy.nodes(); // this returns all nodes
> cy.edges(); // this returns all edges
> ```
>
> If you want to get a specific group of elements or one in particular, you can perform a query like this:
>
> ```
> cy.elements/nodes/edges('[selector =/!= "property"]');   // selector can be id and the property the actual id
> ```

### **Solution:**

To get to the solution, here is what you can do:

```
cy.nodes('[id = "yourId"]').style('background-color', 'desiredColor');
```

Or binding it to an event, idk what your use-case is:

```
cy.unbind('click);  // always unbind before binding an event to prevent binding it twiche/multiple times
cy.bind('click', 'node, edge', function(event) {
    let target = event.target;
  if (target.isEdge()) {
    target.style('line-color', 'green');
  } else {
    target.style({
      'background-color': 'white',
      'border-color': 'blue'
    });
  }
});
```

### **Code example:**

Here is a working example of this method:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px",
        "border-color": "black",
        "background-color": "gray",
        "border-opacity": "1",
        "border-width": "10px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge[label]",
      css: {
        label: "data(label)",
        "text-rotation": "autorotate",
        "text-margin-x": "0px",
        "text-margin-y": "0px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ":selected",
      css: {
        "background-color": "black",
        "line-color": "black",
        "target-arrow-color": "black",
        "source-arrow-color": "black"
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {
    name: "circle"
  }
}));

var info = [{
    name: "Peter",
    next_op_name: "Claire"
  },
  {
    name: "Claire",
    next_op_name: "Mike"
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    next_op_name: "Rosa"
  },
  {
    name: "Rosa",
    next_op_name: "Peter"
  }
];

cy.ready(function() {
  var array = [];
  // iterate over info once
  for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
    array.push({
      group: "nodes",
      data: {
        id: info[i].name, // id is name!!!
        label: info[i].name
      }
    });
    array.push({
      group: "edges",
      data: {
        id: "e" + i,
        source: info[i].name,
        target: info[i].next_op_name,
        label: "e" + i
      }
    });
  }
  cy.add(array);
  cy.layout({
    name: "circle"
  }).run();
});
cy.on("mouseover", "node", function(event) {
  var node = event.target;
  node.qtip({
      content: "hello",
      show: {
        event: event.type,
        ready: true
      },
      hide: {
        event: "mouseout unfocus"
      }
    },
    event
  );
});

cy.unbind('click');
cy.bind('click', 'node, edge', function(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.isEdge()) {
    target.style('line-color', 'green');
  } else {
    target.style({
      'background-color': 'white',
      'border-color': 'blue'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <!-- qtip imports -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/2.7.0/cytoscape-qtip.js"></script>

  <!-- dagre imports -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It would be a bit better to use a mappers in the stylesheet with `ele.data()`.